# How to render Jsonplaceholder data into HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, ajax

I am new to the javascript language and still know nothing about it.
Can anyone tell me how to render data from Jsonplaceholder into an HTML table?

```js
function getDataUsers(url, callback) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        callback(xhr.response);
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.open("get", url);
  xhr.send();
}

getDataUsers(
  "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  function (results) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(results));
  },
  () => {}
);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with some [HTTP overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and learning about [JS Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
After that, I really recomend [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tc8DU14qX6I) - very nicely explained.

Good luck!